# Can anyone help me find a story about an alien who comes to earth and lives with a family and then in the end takes that family to his homeplanet?

Tags: story-identification

I remember some of the story, that the alien travels through space and arrives in a particular place on earth through a door. He has telepathic and mind reading powers and he starts living with a family when they find him in the forest. Everything is going smooth until the people start to get scared of this alien boy and they are going to try to kill him. So he escapes earth along with the family who took care of him.
I do not remember the name of this book or the author. Can someone help me find this book?

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Comment: The Duplicate is slightly iffy, because the person turned out to be talking about two different stories in the anthology, but I count it as close enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect this is Alexander Key's *[The Forgotten Door](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/409320.The_Forgotten_Door)*

[image: Book cover - The Forgotten Door - Boy falling out of a door on a sphere appparently into space]

> Who is the strange boy who can talk to animals and read people's minds? Where does he come from?
>
> The boy, Jon, has lost his memory and does not know. he only knows that he has fallen through the forgotten door to the strange planet, Earth, and that he is in great danger
>
> Soon the family who befriends him is in great danger, too. There is very little time left. Jon must find the secret way back to his planet--before its too late.

The [Kirkus Review](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/alexander-key-4/the-forgotten-door/) indicates that the family do go back with him.

> As the hounds of officialdom descend with dissection clearly in mind, the door through which Jon fell opens, offering him re-entry and the Beans a better world.

FWIW, I did not search for this one, having read it as a child and the "door" description being particularly vivid in my head.

Comment: Did you read it on its own, or in the textbook Riders on the Earth?

Comment: @Buzz I believe on its own. I recognize that cover art. :)

Comment: Yes! This is it ! I had read it as a kid too and the door description was imprinted in my mind too. Thanks a lot