# YA SciFi story of telepathic amnesiac

Tags: story-identification

I remember reading (and also seeing a TV movie adaptation?) about a boy/alien who crawled out of a cave, learned the language by reading everybody's thoughts, and then went back for some reason. There was a scene towards the end with a judge asking him to guess a number, and that's how they verified he was actually a telepath. Does anybody remember this book?

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/62201) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is *The Forgotten Door* by Alexander Key, from 1965.  The scene where he demonstrates the ability (in court) to guess a large number the judge had chosen at random is quite memorable.

[image: The Forgotten Door]

[image]

Per Goodreads:

> Who is the strange boy who can talk to animals and read people's minds? Where does he come from?
>
> The boy, Jon, has lost his memory and does not know. he only knows that he has fallen through the forgotten door to the strange planet, Earth, and that he is in great danger
>
> Soon the family who befriends him is in great danger, too. There is very little time left. Jon must find the secret way back to his planet--before its too late.

There is a one-act play adaptation, although I don't know if it was ever broadcast on television.  Overall, *The Forgotten Door* was a fairly popular children's science fiction book (and was even included, in its entirety, in one elementary school reader).

This book has previously come up:  [Can anyone help me find a story about an alien who comes to earth and lives with a family and then in the end takes that family to his homeplanet?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/176271/can-anyone-help-me-find-a-story-about-an-alien-who-comes-to-earth-and-lives-with/) and [1970's sci-fi short story in 4th grade reading anthology](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/149580/1970s-sci-fi-short-story-in-4th-grade-reading-anthology)